# How to set 14pt to chapter?

Tags: fonts

I want to, that chapter font size be 14pt. I use below code, but that doesn't work. I don't know why. I will gratefull, if someone help me.
`\usepackage{sectsty} \chapterfont{\large\bfseries}`
And this is my class document
`\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}`

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\large\bfseries}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Abc}
xxx
\end{document}
```

This code, make that chapter font size is 12pt, section font size is 12pt, and subsection is 12pt. Section and subsection is ok, but I want to set chapter 14pt. This is my code, which I use.

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\bfseries}


\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startchapter{chapter}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
                                     {\normalfont}}

\makeatother



\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
                                     {\normalfont\itshape}}

\makeatother
``
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try `\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont` in the place of `\large`.

Comment: `\large` will set a larger font depending on your document class. In `article` class at the default 10pt option you want `\Large` not `\large` for 14pt. Please always show a small compete document not a fragment that depends on code not shown.

Comment: I use `\chapterfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\bfseries}`, but  nothnig change. I use `raport`.

Comment: please edit your question so that it shows an example of the problem that you are asking about. We can not guess what you have done if you do not show any code.

Comment: [This MWE](https://pastebin.com/raw/BuxB03r4) produces differing titles for each chapter. So you must be doing some else if it's not working. Can you share what you're doing?

Comment: I added a test document to your question as you are using 12pt `\large` is 14.4pt, if for some reason you need exactly 14pt (why?) use the form that Bernard showed in the first comment. and add `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: I add more code in my post.

Comment: you loaded sectsty to give easy declarations to set the fonts and then you used low level definitions to completely undo _everything_ the package defines! There was no way anyone could have guessed that was the issue before your edit.

Comment: I don't know well latex. So could you help me ?

Comment: we are trying to help but you are making it hard to help.  delete everything from \allsectionsfont to the end of your code section and add the remaining three lines to the document in the question

Comment: I delete everthing  from \allsectionsfont, but which 3 lines should add ?

Comment: I use this code, and now that works. `\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\bfseries}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{17}\selectfont\itshape}` But I want that subsection was no bold.